# What happens with xsl:text?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0, oxygenxml

I have a code which generates a text file using xslt.

It's a rather large amount of data to paste in here so I'll try and only past relevant data.

I have a template which looks like this and this is my starting point

```
<xsl:template match="addrmap[not(@name='ADDRMAP_NAME_NOT_USED')]">
  <xsl:result-document href="{$OUTPUT_DIR}/{@name}_defs_p.vhd">
    <xsl:call-template name="vhdl_header">
      <xsl:with-param name="block" select="."></xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>

<xsl:text>
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

use work.pk_avalon_mm_extif_defs;
</xsl:text>

    <xsl:text>Test 2</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:variable name="offset" select="rdt:all2dec(rdt:resolve_offset(./@offset))"/>
    <xsl:text>Test 3</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="map">
      <xsl:with-param name="offset" select="$offset"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>

    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="enum" mode="map">
  <xsl:text>Test 4</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>Test 5</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

I am using the expression below to track how text is written to my file

```
<xsl:text>Test #</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
```

Running my code **"Test 2"** and **"Test 3"** gets print correctly with no indentation and right after each other. Now **"Test 4"** gets printed with and Indentation of 4 and two lines below **"Test 3"**. **"Test 5"** is also printed correctly IE no indentation and one the next line after **"Test 4"**. It looks like this

```
Test 2
Test 3


    Test 4
Test 5
```

I cannot find why it does this. It looks to me its something that happens when entering the template. because I have a second template execute after this which behaves similar.

If I now take and removes the xsl:text and just have the text raw.

```
<xsl:template match="enum" mode="map">
Test 4<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>Test 5</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

It looks a little different

```
Test 2
Test 3



Test 4
Test 5
```

now **"Test 4"** have the right indentation however it is now 3 lines below **"Test 3"**

I hope this makes sense.

I am using oXygen but I cant seem to debug my way out of this one

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Consider to reduce your problems to minimal but complete samples to allow us to reproduce the problem. So far we can only guess that `xsl:apply-templates mode="map"` which processes all child nodes (including text nodes) outputs some text nodes from the input, either through your own templates or as the built-in templates or your `xsl:mode` settings do that. But you haven't shown any input.

If you only want to process `enum` elements you can try `<xsl:apply-templates select="enum" mode="map"/>`, if you only want to process child elements but not text nodes use `select="*"`. A more radical approach might be to strip white space with `xsl:strip-space`.